# caffe inner_prodcut_param with axis

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I recent read someone's caffe prototxt I found the following thing puzzling. As in the caffe official API :

http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/doxygen/classcaffe_1_1ConcatLayer.html

There is only two choices about "axis" parameter which is either 0 or 1.
However, in that prototxt it declare the "axis: -1", can anyone tell me why? Following is the original prototxt address.

https://github.com/vsubhashini/caffe/blob/recurrent/examples/s2vt/s2vt.prototxt

Answer (score 0):

Caffe allows for axes indices to have negative values like Python indexing:
-1 means the *last* axis.  Consequently, -2 is the one before last axis, and so on.

These indices are equivalent:

```
 0  1  2  3
-4 -3 -2 -1
```

Comment: thanks, one more question. In the caffe prototxt, what does the Include and STAGE parameter mean. A example part of prototxt is like below.

Comment: layer {
  name: "dropFc7"
  type: "Dropout"
  bottom: "frame_fc7"
  top: "frame_fc7"
  dropout_param { dropout_ratio: 0.5 }
  include { stage: "dropFc7" }
}

Comment: @李德健 please do not post questions in comments. ask a new one.